# Sails.js - Get an object (model) using multiple join

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am new to node.js and newer to Sails.js framework.

I am currently trying to work with my database, I don't understand all the things with Sails.js but I manage to do what I want step by step. *(I am used to some PHP MVC frameworks so it is not too difficult to understand the structure.)*

Here I am trying to get a row from my database, using 2 `JOIN` clause. I managed to do this using `SQL` and the `Model.query()` function, but I would like to do this in a "cleaner" way.

So I have 3 tables in my database: meta, lang and meta_lang. It's quite simple and a picture being better than words, here are some screenshots.

**meta**

[image: meta table]

**lang**

[image: lang table]

**meta_lang**

[image: meta_lang table]

What I want to do is to get the row in `meta_table` that match with 'default' meta and 'en' lang (for example).

Here are Meta and Lang models (I created them with `sails generate model` command and edited them with what I needed):

**Meta**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        code : { type: 'string' },
        metaLangs:{
            collection: 'MetaLang',
            via: 'meta'
        }
    }
};
```

**Lang**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        code : { type: 'string' },
        metaLangs:{
            collection: 'MetaLang',
            via: 'lang'
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my MetaLang model, with 3 functions I created to test several methods. The first function, `findCurrent`, works perfectly, but as you can see I had to write SQL. That is what I want to avoid if it is possible, I find it more clean (and I would like to use Sails.js tools as often as I can).

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'meta_lang',
    attributes: {
        title : { type: 'string' },
        description : { type: 'text' },
        keywords : { type: 'string' },
        meta:{
            model:'Meta',
            columnName: 'meta_id'
        },
        lang:{
            model:'Lang',
            columnName: 'lang_id'
        }
    },

    findCurrent: function (metaCode, langCode) {
        var query = 'SELECT ml.* FROM meta_lang ml INNER JOIN meta m ON m.id = ml.meta_id INNER JOIN lang l ON l.id = ml.lang_id WHERE m.code = ? AND l.code = ?';
        MetaLang.query(query, [metaCode, langCode], function(err, metaLang) {
            console.log('findCurrent');
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(metaLang);
            // OK this works exactly as I want (I would have prefered a 'findOne' result, only 1 object instead of an array with 1 object in it, but I can do with it.)
        });
    },

    findCurrentTest: function (metaCode, langCode) {
        Meta.findByCode(metaCode).populate('metaLangs').exec(function(err, metaLang) {
            console.log('findCurrentTest');
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(metaLang);
            // I get what I expected (though not what I want): my meta + all metaLangs related to meta with code "default".
            // What I want is to get ONE metaLang related to meta with code "default" AND lang with code "en".
        });
    },

    findCurrentOthertest: function (metaCode, langCode) {
        MetaLang.find().populate('meta', {where: {code:metaCode}}).populate('lang', {where: {code:langCode}}).exec(function(err, metaLang) {
            console.log('findCurrentOthertest');
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(metaLang);
            // Doesn't work as I wanted: it gets ALL the metaLang rows.
        });
    }
};
```

I also tried to first get my Meta by code, then my Lang by code, and MetaLang using Meta.id and Lang.id . But I would like to avoid 3 queries when I can have only one.

What I'm looking for would be something like `MetaLang.find({meta.code:"default", lang.code:"en"})`.

Hope you've got all needed details, just comment and ask for more if you don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you know what populate is for ? its for including the whole associated object when loading it from the database. Its practically the join you are trying to do, if all you need is row retrieval than quering the table without populate will make both functions you built work.

To me it looks like you are re-writing how Sails did the association. Id suggest giving the Associations docs another read in [Sails documentation: Associations](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations). As depending on your case you are just trying a one-to-many association with each table, you could avoid a middle table in my guess, but to decide better id need to understand your use-case.

When I saw the mySQL code it seemed to me you are still thinking in MySQL and PHP which takes time to convert from :) forcing the joins and middle tables yourself, redoing a lot of the stuff sails automated for you. I redone your example on 'disk' adapter and it worked perfectly. The whole point of WaterlineORM is to abstract the layer of going down to SQL unless absolutely necessary.
 Here is what I would do for your example, first without SQL just on a disk adapter id create the models :

```
  // Lang.js
  attributes: {
    id :{ type:  "Integer" , autoIncrement : true,  primaryKey: true },
    code :"string"
  }
```

you see what i did redundantly here ? I did not really need the Id part as Sails does it for me. Just an example.

```
  // Meta.js
  attributes: {
    code :"string"
  }
```

better :) ?

```
 // MetaLang.js
attributes: 
 {
      title : "string",
      desc : "string",
      meta_id : 
      {
       model : "meta",
      },
     lang_id : 
     {
       model : "lang",    
     }
  }
```

Now after simply creating the same values as your example i run sails console type :

```
 MetaLang.find({meta_id : 1 ,lang_id:2}).exec(function(er,res){
  console.log(res);
 });
```

Output >>>

```
sails> [ { meta_id: 1,
    lang_id: 2,
    title: 'My blog',
    id: 2 } ]
```

Now if you want to display what is meta with id 1 and what is lang with id 2, we use populate, but the referencing for join/search is just as simple as this.

```
sails> Meta_lang.find({meta_id : 1 ,lang_id:2}).populate('lang_id').populate('meta_id').exec(function(er,res){ console.log(res); });
undefined
sails> [ { 
  meta_id: 
     { code: 'default',
       id: 1 },
  lang_id: 
     { code: 'En',
       id: 2 },
    title: 'My blog',
    id: 2 } ]
```

At this point, id switch adapters to MySQL and *then* create the MySQL tables with the same column names as above. Create the FK_constraints and voila. 

 Another *strict* policy you can add is to set up the 'via' and dominance on each model. you can read more about that in the Association documentation and it depends on the nature of association (many-to-many etc.)

To get the same result without knowing the Ids before-hand :

```
sails> Meta.findOne({code : "default"}).exec(function(err,needed_meta){
..... Lang.findOne({code : "En"}).exec(function(err_lang,needed_lang){
....... Meta_lang.find({meta_id : needed_meta.id , lang_id : needed_lang.id}).exec(function(err_all,result){
......... console.log(result);});
....... });
..... });
undefined
sails> [ { meta_id: 1,
    lang_id: 2,
    title: 'My blog',
    id: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I don't have time to test everything right now (I will have a closer look tonight). Just some comments. :) `When I saw the mySQL code it seemed to me you are still thinking in MySQL and PHP which takes time to convert from` => right. ^^" But I had to do SQL because I didn't find how to do it without SQL, I started with `find()` and `populate()` on my objects without success.

Comment: I see you're getting MetaLang object by meta_id and lang_id, what about getting them by meta_code and lang_code? I still don't understand how to do it without having to 1/ Find my Meta by code, 2/ Find my lang by code, 3/ Find my MetaLang with ids.

Comment: Thanks you very much for having spent time on that answer. :)

Comment: To give an example, I'm used to Doctrine ORM in PHP (with Symfony Framework) and I could get my model object MetaLang joining it with Meta where meta.code is "default" and joining with Lang where lang.code is "en", without having to do any SQL or even think about my database structure, as you say. But I didn't find how to do the same with Waterline.

Comment: And (I might seem to be criticizing your answer, I'm not, I really appreciate it! Just trying to understand what I missed ^^), I was trying to understand why you removed collections from my model (because I might need them in other cases), and had a new look at the documentation, I did my [One-to-Many](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html) association as explained, so I'm afraid I don't get why removing it... Yes, in that function I don't need to retrieve all my Meta's MetaLangs, maybe you just wanted to simplify it for that particular case?

Comment: What I'm looking for would be something like `MetaLang.find({meta.code:"default", lang.code:"en"})`.

Comment: No Problem: (cant really formatted any nicer:)
    `sails> Meta.findOne({code : "default"}).exec(function(err,needed_meta){
..... Lang.findOne({code : "En"}).exec(function(err_lang,needed_lang){
....... Meta_lang.find({meta_id : needed_meta.id , lang_id : needed_lang.id}).exec(function(err_all,result){
......... console.log(result);});
....... });
..... });
 sails> [ { meta_id: 1,
    lang_id: 2,
    title: 'My blog',
    id: 2 } ]
    `

Comment: Its an Asynchronous language and framework, you query Lang table and set the callback to query Meta table at the second query callback u already have both ids, you query the third Table and at the third callback is your return trip to the client with the result

Comment: As to why I dropped the collection again for me it was redundundant work, you can drop it but then ull need to take care of the dominance bit in each class, as it doesnt make sense for the blogs object to be saved in the Meta's table etc.. thats a design and performance question thats really up-to-you

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't want to have to get my Meta, then my Lang, then my MetaLang... but I think there isn't any other way. And as it's asynchronous (the part that I really have to work on because not used to it), it's quite logical in the end. - I will (highly probably) accept your answer later, I didn't have time to test anything today but I think I have everything I need. :)

Comment: As for the OneToMany relation, dominance and everything, I will have a closer look at it to understand the best way to work with it.

Comment: The only thing I'm not completely OK with (but got it, it's the way Sails.js works): with that solution (Meta, then Lang, then MetaLang) I assume it makes 3 queries to the database, instead of only 1 if I had used SQL (with Doctrine ORM in PHP you can do that with only 1 query -bad comparison?). Here it's not a big issue: these are really small queries, and there won't be plenty of them on each page. But in general, couldn't it be an issue? (It's a general question, probably not the good place to ask it... And I think I need to understand Node.js and Sails.js better before going into this.)

Comment: well its a very valid question and im not the expert on this unfortuneately, but I guess its fundamental to Node.js vs Other tech, Async vs. Sync. Yes its 3 queries, but 3 non-blocking, super duper fast io read thanks to v8 and Node. Compare it to 1 blocking of the table that will take 3 times the time. In between the 3 fast queries another client might have been served. It really depends on the nature of your application, how much concurrent traffic with low demands vs. single lane traffic with high demand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
findCurrentTest: function (metaCode, langCode) {
    Meta.findByCode(metaCode).populate('metaLangs', {where: {code:langCode}}).exec(function(err, metaLang) {
        console.log('findCurrentTest');
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(metaLang);
    });
},
```

Comment: This returns only the datas from 'meta' table, 'metaLang' is empty. `[{metaLangs:[],code:'default',id:1}]` . I will try other things in that direction, thanks!

Comment: This answer really helps me. I previously didn't realize I could have query on "populate" method.